# Calling client javascript with params from server side in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wcf, rest

I have an ASP.net webpage, that periodically (once in a minute) makes a call to my WCF REST service. My REST service responses some XML data. After getting it I make some further operations on that on server side in my ASP page.Note, this post data process in ASP is required, I can't avoid it. I know my life would be easier without this step, but I must do it.

After I'd like to pass this data in XML format to a client side javascript, that can parse it and show infos to the user based on this data. How can make this call from server side? What is the best pattern/practice to do it?

.net4/VS2010

Comment: To make sure I follow: You get the data from the WCF Web service on the client side and then pass it back to an ASP .NET Page that performs another process on this data and needs to return it back to the client?

Comment: Not exactly: WCF REST->ASP->JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to call a function that already exists, that will load your data to the screen, you can tell the server to return your data and then ajax will grab that data and call a callback function.
if you are not using ajax, you can reload the whole page with the new data.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is not designed to push data from the server to the client. I'm not really familiar with ASP but usually you have the following possibilities to "push" data to a client javascript application via HTTP:

- page reload via meta refresh (which doesn't actually push data;) )
- periodically polling an "job queue" URL using javascript
- comet (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) for an overview)
- Web Sockets (which actually pushes data to the client but is only supported by newer browsers)

I've been using atmosphere (http://atmosphere.java.net/) which works pretty well in java application containers, which provides an abstraction layer over the underlying technology. I don't know if there is something similar out there in the ASP-world.

cheers
Martin

Answer (score 1):

[Tom, in that case just do the following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript.aspx)